# connecting azure website to sql server database on external server

Tags: sql-server-2008, azure, model-view-controller, wcf-data-services

I had hosted my site on Azure and my database to azure sql databse but the problem with azure sql database does not support data encryption and for that reason I have to move my sql database to external server.

Now I do not know how I can connect that sql database to azure site?

I found one solution to use service bus but they used WCF console application as a service bus listener which I do not know how to create and host WCF.

I appreciate code sample if anything I need to do in my code or application other than connection string setup.

Comment: When you said "external server" is that mean a server out of the cloud? If you, the simplest way is to open 1433 outbound port of this server so that you can connect.

Comment: Azure SQL _does_ support encryption, just add `..;Encrypt=True;..` to your connection string.

Comment: Yes, my dedicated database server.